# Regex to match the string with another string Patten in URL or i can use some string class method?

Tags: java, regex

String urlString="http://myApp:8080/new/bin/save/SellerMyPage/WebHome"

i want to check whether above  string  contains the  string "MyPage" between two forward slashes. Also it should be in the end between the slashes and should be prefixed
with some characters. here is the result i am expecting

```
 "http://myApp:8080/new/bin/save/SellerMyPage/WebHome"  should return true
 "http://myApp:8080/new/bin/save/SellerMyPage1/WebHome"  should return false(its not ending with MyPage)
"http://myApp:8080/new/bin/save/MyPage/WebHome"  should return false(MyPage is not prefixed with any any character)
```

Looks like i need to take resort of regex for the same? Would appreciate if  somebody can help me out regarding regex?

If it contains , i want to extract that  string in first case it should return SellerMyPage

For extracting part i used below code snippet but to me iam not convinced it is optimized way. I am sure there should be better way than this?

```
     String extractedElement="";
 String[] urlSpliArray=urlString.split("/");
        for(String urlElement:urlSpliArray)
        if(urlElement.endsWith("MyPage"))
        {
            extractedElement=urlElement;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*/([^/]+MyPage)/.*");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(urlString);
if (m.find()) {
  extractedElement = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks phatfingers for taking me almost close. But extracted element returns SellerMyPage/ but i expect SellerMyPage (not the forward slash).

Comment: i used extractedElement .replaceAll("/", "")  for now to remove it.

Comment: @MSach Are you sure you copied his exact pattern? I was wondering why a extractedElement would contain a slash at the end, so I tried it myself. Using phatfingers' pattern, I do not get a slash at the end of extractedElement.

Comment: Thanks Alderath. It was my bad while coping

Answer (score -1):

Use real regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, don't use `String.split`. You could use the following regex (WARNING: not tested and not escaped for use as string):

```
^.*?([^/]+?MyPage/).*$
```